# How do I change or disable the default sound for tkinter message boxes in python 3

Tags: python, audio, tkinter, messagebox

I want to play a sound and display some information on the screen in my program.
I'm currently using the following:

`winsound.PlaySound('chaching.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
 messagebox.showinfo(
     "Info", "Assigned {} to {}, the password is {}".format(
     id, acc_name, acc_pass))`

However that makes the stupid error noise when the message box is triggered.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10, the following code does not make a sound/bell:

```py
answer = messagebox.askokcancel(
    title='Info',
    message="Assigned {} to {}, the password is {}".format(id, acc_name, acc_pass)),
)
if not answer:
    return 'break'
else:
    # otherwise, do what you got a do:
    pass
```

Comment: Just tested this (Win 10) and further found it didn't matter the messagebox type as the sound was determined from the icon messagebox.showinfo("test","Testing",icon="question") is silent. The icons 'info' and 'warning' cause the bell sound and 'error' causes the error sound.

Comment: @Brandon thank you so much! Adding `icon="question"` was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there's no way to do this; calling `bell()` whenever a `Message` is displayed is part of Tcl/Tk, not something Python/Tkinter adds on top of it.<sup>1</sup>

But you can always use `SimpleDialog` to build a modal dialog that looks just like `MessageBox` but isn't one, and doesn't sound like one.<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sub>1. Well, if you really wanted to reach down into the Tcl code… but you don't.</sub>

<sub>2. IIRC, `SimpleDialog` *does* call `bell()` if you do things like press Esc or hit the close box on a dialog with no cancel button set. But I'm pretty sure that *is* done by Python/Tkinter, not Tcl/Tk, so you can just override the `wm_delete_window` or whichever method is responsible. Or just not create a window without a cancel button.</sub>

Comment: It's not actually done by tcl/tk. Those dialog boxes on windows and osx are supplied by the OS, and so are controlled by the OS rather than the programming language.